# rspec expects doesn't do what I expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot

So I have two specs which I thought are testing the same thing yet one fails while the other one passes. I'm working on an app which has a recurring schedule. If a user creates an trip that recurs it will go ahead and create new trips for each day specified. Here is the first test which fails:

```ruby
it "makes future trips" do
  expect{FactoryGirl.create(:recurring_transportation_trip)}.to change(Trip, :count).by(4)
end
```

The recurring_transportation_trip creates a trip which will make the three future trips via an after_save callback. This test fails with the error "count should have been changed by 4, but was changed by 1".

Here is another test which passes:

```ruby
it "makes future trips" do
  count = Trip.count
  FactoryGirl.create(:recurring_transportation_trip)
  Trip.count == count + 4
end
```

Showing that the correct functionality is there.

The first test is certainly more readable but doesn't actually test what I think it does. Can anyone offer and explaination for why?

-------EDIT-------

Adding the Factory code by request:

```ruby
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :recurring_transportation_trip, :class => :trip do
    collection_time "09:00"
    estimated_duration "60"
    status "Confirmed"
    mileage "30"
    association :collection, :factory => :location
    association :destination, :factory => :location
    association :call, :factory => :recurring_call
  end
end
```

and for the recurring_call

```ruby
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :recurring_call, :class => "Call" do
    recurring true
    recurring_start_date Date.today
    recurring_end_date Date.today + 1.week
    recurring_config [1, 3, 5]
  end
end
```

-------EDIT2-------

Turns out `Trip.count == count + 4` isn't actually asserting anything and the test `Trip.count.should == count + 4` does indeed fail. Thanks @BenediktDeicke for pointing this out.

-------EDIT3-------

In the end it was an error in my application code and I should have trusted the original test from the beginning. Thanks to everyone who took a look. @boulder and @BenediktDeicke thanks for pointing out the lack of assertion mentioned in edit2.

Comment: what happens if you use `change{Trip.count}` instead of `change(Trip, :count)` like that : `expect{FactoryGirl.create(:recurring_transportation_trip)}.to change{Trip.count}.by(4)` same issue ?

Comment: @pjam changing `change(Trip, :count)` to `change{Trip.count}` gives the same result (just noticed the block =p)

Comment: weird indeed, could you post your factory's code ?

Comment: @pjam just edited my previous comment. Didn't notice `Trip.count` was in a block ^.^

Comment: ok, but could you post the factory's code anyway ? I'd like to see what it looks like

Comment: @pjam I've added the factories to my post.

Comment: The other test passes, because there isn't any assertion in it. So most likely the behavior isn't what you think it is. Change `Trip.count == count + 4` to `Trip.count.should == count + 4` to see it - most likely - fail

Comment: Thanks @BenediktDeicke, having the test actually assert something does cause it to fail. When I discover why my code is failing I'll come back and mention it here just for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second test is actually not testing anything, because there's no expectation defined on it.

The line 
`Trip.count == count + 4`
is simply a expression that evaluates to false.

What you're trying to do is:

```
Trip.count.should == count + 4
```

In any case the first test is the one you should trust; it is telling you that there is an error in your application code that you need to investigate.

Comment: You just edited your question seconds before I wrote mine, which made it outdated. If you show us your model callbacks, we may be able to tell you why they're not working as expected.

Comment: Thanks. This is the correct answer. I actually found the error and it was an issue with the application code. However, having a better understanding of expectations in rspec is exactly what I was asking, I just didn't realize it. Credit also to @BenediktDeicke

Answer (score 0):

The by chain matcher is the amount the expected should change by.

```
expect{FactoryGirl.create(:recurring_transportation_trip)}.to change(Trip, :count).by(1)
```

Here is the [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-12/docs/built-in-matchers/expect-change!).

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused, `FactoryGirl.create(:recurring_transportation_trip)` should make one trip which has an after_save callback to make three more. Therefore I expect the Trip count to change by 4 not 1.